# Is this XSS filter secure enough? And if not, could you demonstrate how it could be broken?

Tags: xss, javascript

```
function htmlEntities(n) {
            return String(n).replace(/&/g, "&amp;").replace(/</g, "&lt;").replace(/>/g, "&gt;").replace(/"/g, "&quot;")
}
```

- Replaces `&` with `&amp;`;
- Replaces `<` with `&lt;`
- Replaces `>` with `&gt;`
- Replaces `"` with `&quot;`

If this needs to be more secure, please explain how to break it so I can learn how it can be broken and how to avoid that.

Comment: depending on where the string is being printed, the `'` should be also replaced, otherwise, the user could escape from attribute (eg : `<img src='user input'>`)

Comment: Are you aware of the standard libraries and approaches to do this? OWASP, for example?

Comment: Have you run this code through XSS cheat sheets? https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_Filter_Evasion_Cheat_Sheet

Comment: We need more informations in order to help you.. Where is the string going to be set ?

Comment: Is this for a browser? If so, just use `textContent` to treat it like text and avoid having to escape.

Comment: "secure enough" for what?

Comment: Why did you write a slightly worse `htmlspecialchars()`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

XSS prevention is all about context. You need different strategies depending on what context the untrusted data you are escaping will be inserted into.

While I think your method would be fine inside HTML elements and in HTML attributes in double quotes, you would have problems in the following contexts:

- In HTML attributes with single quotes or without quotes at all, you will be pwned.
- In e.g. a `href` attribute, you would be pwned with e.g. a `javascript:` or `vbscript:` URL.
- In JavaScript string literals using single quotes, you will be pwned.
- In JavaScript string literals using double quotes, an attacker could stop the script from being executed by inserting a newline and thereby cause a syntax error. This could have unexpected and adverse consequences in some circumstances.
- And then there's CSS, which has it's own set of different rules...

For a detailed guide on how to do this right, I strongly recommend [the OWASP XSS prevention cheat sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_(Cross_Site_Scripting)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet). I think the main take home lessons of all this is: **XSS is complicated. Don't rely on your own home brewed solution to stop it.** Use a well tested library instead.

(And [Alexander O'Mara](https://security.stackexchange.com/users/50311/alexander-omara) is absolutely right in his comment. If this is in the browser, just go with `textContent`.)